# Kerberos WAS 7 fallback to application authentication(LDAP)

Tags: java, authentication, websphere, kerberos, fallback

We have implemented kerberos based SSO for my application, it is integrated with domain1.com users and it is working fine. But there are few accounts which are not in domain1.com domain, they are in domain2.com so we wanted to provide our custom login screen for entering user credentials and then we wanted to authenticate it with ldap with our own java code. So the scenario is, if user is trying to access my application then sso should happen automatically if he falls in domain1.com otherwise showing the customised login screen where in he enters user credentials then application will authenticate it and grants the application resources. 
How to achieve this?

Comment: technology information: we are using websphere 7 on solaris enviroment.Jave/J2EE application

Answer (score 1):

Websphere 7+ has support for fall back to application authentication mechanism.

In admin console: Do the following steps.

Goto **Security > Global security > SPNEGO web authentication**

Select **Allow fall back to application authentication mechanism**

You can find more information [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7JFU_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/tsec_SPNEGO_config.html?cp=SS7JFU_7.0.0%2F1-8-30-2-5-1-2-0)

Comment: Thanks for your response, we tried this, for "Allow fall back to application authentication mechanism" to by default basic authentication(pop up) is authenticating with domain1.com only, we wanted to have "form based authentication" which can authenticate with domain2.com.This is not working as expected. If we have to implement "Form based authentication" as a fall back mechanism then do we need to make any changes in kerberos settings?

Comment: What is happening after you enter credentials in pop-up? Is it prompting a pop-up again? And what is happening if cancel the pop-up in the first pop-up?

Comment: After entering the credentials in the pop up window then it is authenticating with the domain1.com , it is working fine but my requirement is different, as a fallback authentication . i want to authenticate the entered user credentials with domain2.com.( i have written my own java code to authenticate with domain2.com ) so how set up fall back mechanism to call my own java servlet code

Comment: By default websphere expects the user from domain1.com. It just doesn't know the user belongs to domain2.com or something else. Fall back mechanism kicks in only after validation of credentials against domain1.com is failed. Have you tried providing the credentials in pop-up and see what happens?